# error comparision between pointer and integer

Tags: c

C Problem  statement: Search an array of integers to find the first first negative integer, if one exists , return its position in the array.
I am aware that I can do this by using indexing, however, I am just wondering why is the program not going into the if condition? Even if I do the casting the code never goes inside if condition.

```
void find_negative(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0; 
    //ignore the first string of arguments because it will be "./problem1.3.c"
    for(i =1; i<argc;i++)
    {
        if(*(argv+i)==2) <-------------------------this is where I get stuck (problem)
        {
            printf("found it at %d location.\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("All positive.\n");
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
   find_negative(argc, argv);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `*(argv+i)` is **exactly equivalent** to `argv[i]`.

Comment: @celeritas : `*(argv+1)` has type `char*` not `char`, so comparing to `'2'` is just as incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `(argv+i)` is `char**`.
The type of `*(argv+i)` is `char*`.

In the line,

```
if(*(argv+i)==2)
```

you are trying to compare a `char*` with 2, whose type is `int`. That explains the compiler error messages.

Perhaps you want to extract an integer from the argument and compare it with 2. Then, you need to use:

```
if(atoi(*(argv+i))==2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things to note:

1. `*(argv + i)` is exactly equivalent to `argv[i]`. There is no difference whatsoever in this particular code.
2. `argv` has type `char **` (a pointer to a pointer to char), so `*(argv + i)` has type `char *` (a pointer to char). You are comparing this directly to the integer value 2, which is why the compiler is giving you grief, because it is rare to ever compare pointers to integers.
3. Comparing a string `"2"` to an integer value 2 won't work, they are different types entirely. If the program is receiving its input via command line arguments, you should parse the input into an actual binary integer.

As an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        long value = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
        if (value < 0)
        {
            printf("Found a negative integer at position %d\n", i);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // if we get here then there were no negative integers in the input
    puts("No negative integers in input");
    return 1;
}
```

The function I used above is documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html).

Answer (score 0):

The input, argv is an array of characters. You probably first need to parse it and convert it to an array of integers.